# Large file parse and import PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, scalability

I have a large csv file (around 700MB) that I am trying to parse and insert into a MySQL database. I read the csv (around 4x10^6 rows) line by line and parse the records to insert. I then insert the records into the database in batches of about 10k records per batch. There are a few things during parsing, e.g. converting a duration of format `11d 12:34:56` into number of hours using `preg_match`.

```
preg_match('/(?P<days>\d+)d (?P<hours>\d+)?P<minutes>\d+)?P<seconds>\d+)/', $hoursUsed, $matches);
```

The script takes about 40 minutes to completely parse the file and insert all records into the database. The questions that I have here are: 
* What should be expected time? I wonder if 40 minutes is normal or not?
* Could the parsing of the csv file be

I am parsing a file(csv) of size around 700MB in PHP (around 4x10^6 rows) but it is taking around 40 minutes to parse the file. I am trying to optimize the parsing but only able to optimize it from 45 to 40 minutes. My questions are:

- What should be expected time? I wonder if 40 minutes is normal or not?
- I do this with the request so there is no response until the file is completely parsed and everything is inserted. Is there a better way to delegate this to an asynchronous process?

FYI I am using CakePHP.

Comment: I'm just going to put it out there, if one of your major concerns is speed, you probably shouldn't be using PHP. In any case, parsing 700MB of data line by line is going to be slow, especially when regex matching each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LOAD DATA INFILE` would speed things up considerably. Just load the duration value in a `CHAR` field and let MySQL process it later.

That way, you leave the data processing to the database, which will be significantly faster than PHP.

Further, 40 minutes sounds not too bad for 700MB and 4 million records. Of course it all depends on the code, the machine, etc.

Comment: The format of the file is not exactly CSV. I need to skip some lines (don't know how many) from the top and I don't want to import all the columns into the database and I want to apply a manual transformation on one of the columns to convert the duration to number of hours. I'm not sure if all that is possible with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: I'd say skipping shouldn't be a problem. As I say in my answer, my advice is to load all the data verbatim into the database, and after that, process any data that needs processing, using SQL statements. MySQL also has regular expressions. MySQL is way better at handling large amounts of data than PHP is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LOAD DATA INFILE` command if at all possible. It's crazy fast.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

You can construct a CSV import with the options `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` and `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

You should be able to execute such a statement from PHP, but note that file path must be full and accessible to MySQL. Also if your mysql server is on another host to your PHP filesystem you may need a workaround.

Comment: The format of the file is not exactly CSV. I need to skip some lines (don't know how many) from the top and I don't want to import all the columns into the database and I want to apply a manual transformation on one of the columns to convert the duration to number of hours. I'm not sure if all that is possible with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: some of this you can do with INFILE. I think you have to decide then whether speed is your primary concern. If it is then I'd dump it into a temporary table, manipulate it and then export and import it again.